# Как отправить сообщение в любой мессенджер?

Tags: flutter, dart

Подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку в моем приложении, происходила отправка сообщения с информацией в мессенджер (W/a, telegram(любой из них)). Есть какой-нибудь пакет, предназначенный для этого? или любые другие решения?

Более подробно. Пользователь добавляет товар в корзину, переходит в нее, вписывает своей номер и... весь товар(его названия) и номер должны отправиться в любой мессенджер

Comment: Набросал что смог

Comment: сяп) (Спасибо, т.е.)

Comment: @МихаилРебров большое спасибО! Надеюсь, мне это поможет!

Comment: Пишите если что - постараюсь помочь. (в профиле есть тг если понадобится пингануть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Share Plus

Можно использовать

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

```dart
Share.share('Текст сообщения, который необходимо передать');
```

#### Android Intent

Если приложение собирается конкретно под андроид, то можно использовать Intent'ы, которые служат для передачи управления и данных другим приложениям

Для этого нужно использовать https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'action_send',
    data: 'some data'
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```

#### URL Launcher

Для iOS можно использовать
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Он, кстати, подойдет и для андроида, т.ч. если подходит то можно использовать и его

В данном пакете вы можете запустить что-то за счет связи приложений с конкретными URI, такими как

- `https:<URL>`
- `mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>`
- `tel:<phone number>`  `tel:+1-555-010-999`
- `sms:<phone number>`  `sms:5550101234`
- `file:<path>`
- также поддерживается запуск других приложений, связанных с конкретными URI, но возможность их отправки зависит от платформы и установленных у пользователя приложений.
  Ниже рассмотрим подробнее один такой пример:

##### Отправка сообщения в WhatsApp с помощью url_launcher

Также имеются варианты с помощью `url_launcher` создать сообщение в WhatsApp с заданными текстом и заранее определенному пользователю.

добавляем зависимость:
*pubspec.yaml*

```yaml
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
```

В самом простом виде это выглядит вот так вот:

```dart
String message = "Hello there!";
await launch("https://wa.me/+79037474031/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");
```

Но тут, стоит учитывать, что в Android и iOS обрабатываются разные урлы.

как-то так:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

  // ...

  String url(String phone, String message) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "https://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
    } else {
      return "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phone=${Uri.parse(message)}";
    }
  }

  Future<void> _makeWhatsAppMessage(String phone, String message) async {
    await launch(url(phone, message));
  }
  
  // ...

  void _someButtonHandler() {
    _makeWhatsAppMessage("+79037474031", "Допустим, Здравствуйте!");
  }

  // ...
```

#### Запасной вариант

Ну и если этого не хватило, то всегда можно написать платформа-ориентированный код на `Java`/`kotlin` или на `Objective C` / `Swift`

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: Да, он быстрый как раз. Плюс я не такой уж продвинутый Flutter разработчик. Я им по приколу и для себя что-то делаю...Я больше по бекенду)

Comment: Это вы зря, набегут такие же зеленые как я и замучают вопросами, хех

Comment: @Daniil, когда есть время - не грех ответить, ну а когда нет... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Дай бог вам здоровья)

Comment: @Daniil, Вы опробуйте сначала. (пишите если что не получится)